# Calcular determinante de una matriz cuadrada como array bidimensional

Tags: java

Me gustaría hacer un algoritmo que al darle una matriz cuadrada calculase su determinante.

Tenia pensado hacerlo por el método de Gauss, haciendo ceros por debajo de la diagonal y multiplicando los que están en la diagonal, lo que tengo ahora son varios for loops anidados que llevan cuenta de las filas, columnas y elemento que queremos hacer cero.

Se utiliza la formula: a = -b/c donde a es el numero que tenemos que multiplicar a la fila c, c es la fila que tiene ceros a la izquierda del elemento seleccionado y b es la fila que queremos que su elemento se cero.

Lo que tengo de momento no sirve, me he quedado atascado ya que no se me da muy bien java y los for anidados. Cualquier respuesta o recomendación ayuda, muchas gracias.

```
for(int z = 0; z<orden-1 ; z++){
 double x = 0; double a = 0;
 for(int i = 1+z; i <orden-z; i++){
  while(x=0){
   for(int n = i-1;n<orden;n++){
    x = m[n][z]
   }
  }
  #break for z
 }
}
```

Mi código es terrible pero agradecería mucho si alguien me pudiera dar un empujón para seguir.